# Debugging android application

Tags: php, android, eclipse, debugging

Hai I am new in android development and I am little bit confused about debugging the app.Actually what is the purpose of debugging in android app?.eg:if I develop an application and fix the errors in the logcat and put it in the paplaystore.do I need use the debugg tool in eclipse? NOTE:if debugging is necessary give a correct way for me.I am big zero in debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging is a process of locating and eliminating bugs. So, the purpose of debugging an app is to make it bug-free (or as close to it as possible). The debugging tool is meant to make this process easier, but it is by no means mandatory - you can use whatever method you like to find and fix errors in your code. As for the specific instructions on how to debug Android app with Eclipse, I suggest you start here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html

Comment: Ok is there any debugging tool is avaliable?

Comment: Eclipse has a good debugger. Check this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html